# Call C++ virtual functions through C struct of function pointers

Tags: c++, c, abi, vtable

I'm creating a C-wrapper for a C++ class:

```
class IObject {
public:
  virtual int getValue() const;
  virtual ~IObject() = default;
};

class Object: public IObject {
public:
  virtual int getValue() const { return 123; }
};
```

Inspired [openh264's C API](https://github.com/cisco/openh264/blob/master/codec/api/svc/codec_api.h), I have the following code:

```
// object.h
#pragma one

#ifdef __cplusplus
class IObject {
 public:
  virtual int getValue() const = 0;
  virtual ~IObject() = default;
};

extern "C" {
#else
typedef struct IObjectVtable IObjectVtable;
typedef IObjectVtable const* IObject;

struct IObjectVtable {
  int (*getValue)(IObject*);
};
#endif

int makeObject(IObject**);
int freeObject(IObject*);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}  // extern "C"
#endif
```

```
// object.cpp
#include "object.h"

class Object : public IObject {
 public:
  virtual int getValue() const override { return 123; }
};

extern "C" {
int makeObject(IObject** obj) {
  *obj = new Object;
  if (*obj == nullptr) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

int freeObject(IObject* obj) {
  delete obj;
  return 0;
}
}
```

In main.c, I use Object as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "object.h"

int main() {
  IObject* obj;
  makeObject(&obj);
  printf("%d\n", (*obj)->getValue(obj));    /** Calling getValue */
  freeObject(obj);
  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and correctly prints "123", but I need to pass obj as an argument of getValue(). Is it possible to avoid this, i.e., simply call `obj->getValue()`?

According to the documentation, openh264 can do that, but I don't understand how/why it works:

```
ISVCDecoder *pSvcDecoder;            //similar to IObject* obj; 
WelsCreateDecoder(&pSvcDecoder);     //similar to makeObject(&obj);
pSvcDecoder->Initialize(&sDecParam); //similar to obj->getValue(); 
                                     //  not (*obj)->getValue(obj)
```

Comment: It's odd that your `make` function takes a double pointer rather than the `malloc`-style just returns a pointer.

Comment: No, it's not possible in C. Are you sure that openh264 actually *needs* the pSvcDecoder parameter?

Comment: Why don't you write a macro or auto-generate it so function calls of the form `x_y(o, ...)` turn into `o->y(...)` inside the implementation? No look-up table required, but you will need to enumerate all the functions you want to map.

Comment: Microsoft work this trick to implement C interfaces to COM objects, but only because they mandate the layout of the vtable.  In general, you can't rely on that.

Comment: Are you sure that openh264 uses this "trick"?

Comment: The openh264 has two parameters in their C API function pointer: `long (*Initialize) (ISVCDecoder*, const SDecodingParam* pParam);` ... are you sure you are looking at their C documentation?

Comment: @user253751 Me?  No, far from certain.  It's Microsoft's own compiler that does this, and some others might have followed suit.

Comment: @user253751  see [openh264/codec_api.h](https://github.com/cisco/openh264/blob/master/codec/api/svc/codec_api.h#L473)

Comment: @Eljay The usage is from the comments in the source file . But now I think about it, the documentation could be for the C++ API. The C interface seems to require the 'self' pointer as parameter (that's how the interface is used in test/api/c_interface_test.c_.

Comment: Well there's your answer then: it's not possible and openh264 doesn't do it.